# Java Thread to find System Time

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, time

I used bellow thread to find system time. But there is a problem here. It always shows 12:11:-- PM and seconds run but after 60 seconds 12:11 no change in minutes again seconds run..My computer original time is 12:24 PM..what is the problem here.sorry for my bad English..

```
public void statTime(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {                            
                    java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:MM:ss a");
                    jLabel1.setText(sdf.format(d));
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: I run this method in the constructor(initcomponent)

Comment: try using mm instead of MM

Comment: jLabel1.setText() should be invoked in AWT - use SwingUtilities.invokeLater()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MM` is month in year - try `mm` in your formatter string

Answer (score 0):

Better use System time using following code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:MM:ss a");
jLabel1.setText(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

Comment: this also works but what's the different between my code and this one..is it easy to run than my code